# Concept of Index in Vim

Tags: vim

Using Vim, how can I print the numbers, say, 1 through 100 on consecutive lines?

e.g.

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   .
>   .
>   100

Comment: I'm not looking for line numbering, just giving a simplified example of a need that I have.

Comment: type i to go into insert mode. Type 1, hit return, type 2, hit return,  and keep going until you have 100.

Comment: @PaulTomblin: I hope you're being sarcastic; obviously, I want to do this in one step...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type:

```
1
```

Then record a macro:

```
qa (start recording a macro stored in register a)
yy (copies the line)
p (inserts that line below)
CTRL+A (increases number by one)
q (stops recording)
```

Next you can invoke that macro 99 times, by:

```
99@a
```

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
:call append( 0, range(1,100) )
```

First parameter is line number to begin the insert. Use `line()` function to choose another one.

Answer (score 3):

- Type <kbd>1</kbd> on the first line in insert mode. Leave insert mode.
- Then enter in 'macro mode' with <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>
- type <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>
- Leave macro mode by retyping <kbd>q</kbd>
- Now type <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to invoke 98 times the macro creating the new line and increasing by one the count

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple for loop:

```
:for i in range(1, 100) | silent put = i | endfor
```

Comment: Very nice one. Other possibility is `for i in range(1,100) | call setline(i,i) | endfor`

Answer (score 1):

In insert mode: <kbd>CTRL-R</kbd>`=join(range(1,100),"\n")`<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you're not in insert mode it's tricky because you have to escape `"` and `|` :

```
:put =join(range(1,100),\"\n\")
```

Comment: `:pu=range(1,100)` is all that is need.  No join.